# Real-linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

> Identify elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by column vectors, so that
> $\mathbb{C}$ corresponds to elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ via
> $$\mathbb{R}^2 \ni \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \longleftrightarrow x + iy \in \mathbb{C}.$$
>
> Show that a real-linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, represented
> by a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix},$$
> corresponds to a complex linear transformation of $\mathbb{C}$ if and
> only if $a = d$ and $b = -c$.

I know that the question of the matrix representation of complex numbers has been asked before in several different forms on this site. However, when I consulted those other pages, they didn't help me to understand my problem above and the particular way it is phrased.

My start was to take the matrix of the real-linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, and apply it to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax + by \\ cx + dy \end{pmatrix}$$
However, I wasn't sure where to go from there. I am thinking that there is some property of a linear transformation that will come into play, but I am not sure how. The wording of the question itself is also confusing to me.

Comment: You need to show
\begin{align*}
L(z_1*z_2) = z_1 L(z_2)
\end{align*}
for any complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ if and only if $a=d$ and $b=-c$, where
\begin{align*}
L(z) = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = ax + by + i(cx + dy).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a complex linear transformation $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ they mean a map defined by $x+iy \mapsto (\alpha + \beta i)(x+ iy)$ where $\alpha + \beta i$ is a fixed complex number. Since $$(\alpha + \beta i)(x+iy)=(\alpha x - \beta y)+(\beta x+\alpha y)i$$ this map is just $$(x,y) \mapsto (\alpha x - \beta y,\beta x+\alpha y)$$ which is equivalent to $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \alpha&-\beta\\\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}$$